# Sockets emit method doesn't work on client - Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am working on Socket IO with Node JS and pure Javascript on client side. When the connections on both ends is established, the message is passed from server to the client successfully, but on a button click the socket doesn't emit anything to the server, I don't know what is the problem.

**Server Side Code**

```js
const phantom = require('phantom');
const ev = require('events');
const event = new ev.EventEmitter();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const ms_connect = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '',
  database: 'scrapper_db'
});
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const internetAvailable = require("internet-available");
const body_parser = require('body-parser');
const server = app.listen(8080, function() {
  console.log('Listening on 8080');
});
const io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
            B A S I C   A P P   R O U T I N G    F U N C T I O N S
    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));
app.use(body_parser.json());

app.get("/", function(req, res) {

  res.sendFile("/index.html");

})
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
                         G L O B A L   F U N C T I O N S
    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function Globals() {

  this.socketConnection = async function() {
    let p = new Promise(function(res, rej) {
      io.on("connection", function(socket) {
        if (socket.connected) {
          res(socket);
        } else {
          rej("Socket Connection Error !");
        }
      })
    })
    return await p;
  }
  this.databaseConnection = async function() {
    let p = new Promise(function(res, rej) {
      ms_connect.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          rej({
            success: false,
            data: err
          });
        } else {
          res({
            success: true
          });
        }
      })
    })
    return await p;
  }
}





/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
                        G L O B A L   F U N C T I O N S
    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function ScrapJobs(socket) {

  var _this = this;

  this.init = function() {
    console.log(socket.client.id);
  }

}

var GL = new Globals();

GL.socketConnection().then(function(s) {
  s.emit("Hi");
  s.on("Nady", function() {
    console.log("I am from client");
  })
  new ScrapJobs(s).init();
})
```

> The above code send emits the "Hi" to the client successfully.

**Client Side Code**

```js
function App() {

  this.socketConnection = async function() {

    var socket = io('http://localhost:8080');
    let p = new Promise(function(res, rej) {
      socket.on('connect', function() {
        if (socket.connected) {
          res(socket);
        }
      })
    })
    //returns the socket if connected
    return await p;
  }

}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
                         E V E N T S   S C R I P T S
    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function _(el) {

  this.el = el;

  this.ev = function(e, callback) {
    switch (arguments.length) {
      case 2:
        {
          this.el.addEventListener(e, callback);
          break;
        }
    }
    return this;
  }

}

function id(a) {
  return new _(document.getElementById(a))
}

function cl(a) {
  return new _(document.getElementsByClassName(a))
}

function tg(a) {
  return new _(document.getElementsByTagName(a))
}

function qs(a) {
  return new _(document.querySelector(a))
}

function qa(a) {
  return new _(document.querySelectorAll(a))
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
                                       C O D E    
    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
function ScrapJobs(st) {

  var _this = this;
  var socket = st;

  socket.on("Hi", function() {
    console.log("I am called from server");
  })


  this.attachListeners = function() {

    qs("#init-scrap").ev("click", _this.startScrapping);
    qs("#play-scrap").ev("click", _this.playScrapping);
    qs("#pause-scrap").ev("click", _this.pauseScrapping);
    qs("#stop-scrap").ev("click", _this.stopScrapping);

  }

  this.startScrapping = function() {
    console.log("I am clicked");
    console.log(st.id);
    st.emit("Nady");
  }

}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
                         I N S T A N T I A T E    A P P 
    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

window.onload = function() {
  if (document.readyState == 'complete') {

    var app = new App();

    app.init("scrap_jobs").then(function() {
      app.attachListeners().then(function() {
        app.socketConnection().then(function(sock) {
          new ScrapJobs(sock).attachListeners();
        })
      })
    });

  }
}
```

> In the client side scripts, when I click the button, then It doesn't emits the "Nady" event.

Comment: Do you see the console.log("I am clicked"); being printed?

Comment: Yes @itsundefined

Comment: The reason that it is not working is in the backend. I noticed a very big error. You are using async/await with promises ON the events that are not fired only once! You cannot use promises for events since the code will not run only one time but everytime a client connects.

Comment: Yes, that is the basic problem, the code only runs one time, I don't know how to solve that @itsundefined

Comment: You need to stop using promises on the socketConnection but instead use a callback. This will fix the problem. Promises are designed to work for async jobs that run and resolve to a specific value. Here you have an event. It doesn't resolve to a specific value but it fires events every single time someone connects. You cannot just not use callbacks because of that reason. If you know express.js it's the same concept when you define middleware/callbacks on routes that you can't use promise and instead provide a function that gets the request and response.